# Is a visa to Poland required for a Russian spouse of a Polish citizen?

Tags: visas, schengen, poland, family, russian-citizens

I am a holder of a Russian passport and my husband is a Polish citizen. We both live and work in the UK. I have received my *family member of EEA national* card, good for 5 years. We would like to travel to Poland together. On the website of the Polish embassy it clearly states that if we are traveling together, I do not require a visa, however in the embassy they were sure that I do need a visa. Could anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 5):

You do not need a visa.  The relevant directive is [2004/38/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1461679977057&uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616).

Article 5, paragraph 2 says:

> Family members who are not nationals of a Member State shall only be required to have an entry visa in accordance with Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 or, where appropriate, with national law. **For the purposes of this Directive, possession of the valid residence card referred to in Article 10 shall exempt such family members from the visa requirement.**

(Emphasis added.)

Article 10, paragraph 1 says:

> The right of residence of family members of a Union citizen who are not nationals of a Member State shall be evidenced by the issuing of a document called ‘Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen’ no later than six months from the date on which they submit the application. A certificate of application for the residence card shall be issued immediately.

You have indicated that your residence card is a "family member of EEA national" card, so I assume that it is in fact the article 10 card that serves to exempt you from the visa requirement.

Comment: IMHO we need a canonical QA for this EU spouse business. Want to take care of it?

Comment: @JoErNanO Yes, I do, but I don't have time to do it now and may not have time before tomorrow.  Did you invite me to chat?  I've never received a chat invitation before and I am not quite sure what to make of it.

Comment: Excellent. I invited you to chat, yes. I wanted to discuss this idea without invading the comment space, but you weren't pingable there. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO was a canonical QA for this ever written?